# React Material UI Switch Label Placement

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, label, uiswitch

I'm trying to create a custom switch using the Material UI Switch component (found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/)). I have placed a label to the right of my switch, however, the placement is too close to the switch. I was wondering if there's a way to adjust the spacing between the switch and the label? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
return (
    <FormGroup>
    <Typography component="div">
      <Grid component="label" container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
      <Grid item></Grid>
        <Grid item>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<AntSwitch checked={state.checkedC} onChange={handleChange} name="checkedC"/>}
          label= {state.checkedC? 'On' : 'Off'}
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Typography>
  </FormGroup>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few different ways you can tackle this issue. It's usually good etiquette to mention what you have tried. ;)

In any case, here's one approach,  the Grid component:

```
     <FormGroup>
        <Typography component="div">
          <Grid
            component="label"
            container
            alignItems="center"
            alignContent="space-between"
            xs={12}
            spacing={3}
          >
            <Grid item>
              <Switch
                checked={state.checkedB}
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="checkedB"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>{state.checkedA ? "On" : "Off"}</Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Typography>
      </FormGroup>
```

Here's another approach using plain old CSS.

```
    <FormGroup>
        <Typography component="div">
         
              <Switch
                checked={state.checkedB}
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="checkedB"
              />
            
            <span style={{paddingLeft:'2em'}}>{state.checkedA ? "On" : "Off"}</span>
        </Typography>
      </FormGroup>
```

You can see both in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-spacing-7w1kn

Please note that you are using a combination of Ant Design and Material Design components there in your original code snippet. This is probably unwise. Mixing CSS can lead to weird unintended side effects. In the code examples above, I swapped out the Ant Design Toggle for the Material Design one.